# Mogoose findOneAndUpdate Callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am recieving an error when I try to update an existing document. I have looked at other solutions but I am unable to solve my issue.

Error:

```
MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]
```

Code:

```
formSchemas.findOneAndUpdate({'email':email, 'condition1': condition1, 'condition2': condition2},
        { $set: { "v1": v1, "v2": v2,
          "v3": v3, "v4": v4,
          "v5": v5 }},
          {new: true},
          {returnOriginal:false},
           function(err, doc){
            if (err){
              console.log(err);
              return res.send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Error somewhere!'
              });
            } 
            return res.send({
              success: true,
              message: 'Updated!'
            });
        }); // findoneandupdate
```

Where v1, v2.. are the things I want to update in mongo and the names of the fields in mongo.
Not sure why the callback is not a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`findOneAndUpdate` expects up to 4 arguments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), all of them are optional:

> [conditions] «Object»
>
> [update] «Object»
>
> [options] «Object» optional see Query.prototype.setOptions()
>
> [options.lean] «Object» if truthy, mongoose will return the document
>   as a plain JavaScript object rather than a mongoose document. See
>   Query.lean().
>
> [callback] «Function»

While 5 arguments was provided, `{returnOriginal:false}` is the one that isn't needed and was confused with callback argument.

`returnOriginal` isn't a valid option in current Mongoose versions. In case new document should be returned instead of original, this is the case for `new` option, which is already used:

> new: bool - if true, return the modified document rather than the 
>   original. defaults to false (changed in 4.0)

It should be:

```
formSchemas.findOneAndUpdate({'email':email, 'condition1': condition1, 'condition2': condition2},
        { $set: { "v1": v1, "v2": v2,
          "v3": v3, "v4": v4,
          "v5": v5 }},
          {new: true},
           function(err, doc){
           ...
           }
);
```

Callback API is obsolete, Mongoose is well-suited to work with promises.